# Parameterize SQL command using IN key word

Tags: c#, entity-framework, security, entity-framework-6

I am using c# + EF6 running into an issue when trying to parameterize a SQL command. In rare cases I have to use the Context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sqltext).

The issue is this:

the query that is executed is using an IN keyword e.g.

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID in (@ids)
```

@ids is a list of integers - if there is a single int then the query runs ok due to implicit conversion:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (@ids)',N'@ids nvarchar(7)',@ids=N'1'
```

but when there is a list of items then it will fail with a conversion error

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE ID IN (@ids)',N'@ids nvarchar(7)',@ids=N'1,2' 
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '1,2' to data type int.
```

How can I structure the parameter or sq to work using sql parameters?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Can we see your c# code please.

Comment: Have you thought about adding a separate parameter for each ID? Ex: `WHERE ID in (@id1, @id2, @id3)`? It's okay to manipulate the SQL string, so long as you don't put any user input directly in the string.

Comment: if you have `List<int>` for id's you can do `.Where(x=>ids.contains(x.Id))`

Comment: You can add a SQL user-defined table type with an integer column, then pass a populated instance of that to the parameterized query via EF.  I can give you an example as an answer if that sounds like a reasonable option.

Comment: @Baral its just running execute command off db context

Comment: @mason good shout that will likely work, not too many ids otherwise string might look exceptionally long - will update soon

Comment: @mars-red although valid in this case I'm trying not to add schema, so simple solution is preferred.